# Raspberry Pi 4 booting/working slow

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, sd-card, raspberry-pi-os

Recently my RPi 4 got crashed and I had to reboot my sd card with OS, I was using the Raspbian's 7th april 2021 release, but when I loaded it again my pi started working slow it even booted in 2-3 mins, browser takes 1-2 minute to load, the solutions I tried:

- changed SD card thrice
- no voltage issue I've checked it
- tried the new bullseye release too
- tried 32 bit OS(default) from pi imager tool

My RPi details:
Raspberry Pi 4 model B
8 GB RAM

Comment: `no voltage issue i've checked it` ... what does that mean? ... how did you check the voltage?

Comment: have you tried booting from USB

Comment: @jstola i’ve tried the command for cpu throtlling also i don’t see any voltage icon on my pi screen

Comment: @Bravo no i haven’t tried that

Answer (score 0):

it's fixed now the issue was with sd card i changed it for the 7th and last time with and hp 64gb class 10 card and now it's working